# Lower border of search bar input container not appearing - React Native

Tags: react-native, searchbar, react-native-textinput

My current search bar looks like this ([lower border does not appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGd1y.png)).

This is its current code:

```
<SearchBar
  containerStyle={{
    backgroundColor: "white",
    padding: 10,
    borderBottomColor: "transparent",
    borderTopColor: "transparent",
  }}
  inputContainerStyle={{
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: COLORS.gray,
  }}
  onChangeText={updateBusca}
  lightTheme
  round
  value={busca}
  onSubmitEditing={() => filterGlossary()}
/>
```

How do I make it appear?

Thanks

Comment: You need to share your SearchBar code as well. Are you using built in TextInput component or any other package?

Comment: No, I'm just using SearchBar from @rneui/themed.